# VS2019-Preview-Professional-Debug mode Intereger values are showing in some hash type

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visualstudio 2019 preview professional, But when I am going to debug the code interger values are showing in some xxx009 like this.
I am not sure any debug options has chenged or not.
Can anyone please suggeted de we need to change any options in tools.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Right click, untick "Hexadecimal Display".  Programmers do need to learn hex.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 1):

Just right click anywhere inside the Watch window and uncheck "Hexadecimal Display"

**Screenshot**

[image]